# How to change fill color of svg group element?

Tags: svg

I am facing some issue in svg if i am changing fill color of second group element then it's changing first g element fill color also. Both are in same position . Is there any way to change color of second g element without changing first g element fill color.

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%">

  <!-- draw rectangle -->
  <g>
  <g transform="translate(50,50)">
    <path d="M0,0 150,0 150,50 0,50" style="fill:red;" />
  </g>
    <g transform="translate(50,50)">
    <path d="M0,0 350,0 350,100 0,150" style="fill:green;" />
  </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example code works as intended, it sets the first element red the second green. However since these items overlap, are opaque and have no whitespace only the element at the top (2nd) is shown.

To see that it works you can try:

- Removing the translate so can see both colored blocks
- Changing the opaque fill to one with an alpha channel making it slightly transparent will also shown both items (try replacing `fill:green` with `fill: rgba(123,123,123,0.5)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the second element is being covered by the first one. You can simply use the css `z-index` property. The element you want to display on the top should have a higher z index than that of the other one.

Comment: There is no z-index in svg . but we can change order that i know but is there any approach

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
svg g:nth-child(2) path{
  fill:Yellow;
}
```